# Connect postgreSQL sever in spring boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm trying to connect a remote postgreSQL server to my spring boot application but I'm not sure how should I update the `application.properties` file.

For example hostname of the postgreSQL sever is `xyz.companyname.com` and port is `5432`
What should I update in `application.properties` ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure you have a Postgresql driver available in your dependencies. These are the changes you can make

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://xyz.companyname.com:5432/my_db
spring.datasource.username=your_username
spring.datasource.password=your_password
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
```

This is from a gradle file, but it should be easy to convert it to your prefered build tool.

```
implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.0")
```

[This link is really useful for troubleshooting questions like that](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html)